# Is it good practice to use "View" for grouping?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I wanted to know is it good practice to use "Views" (from Object library) for groping e.g. I'm putting two "Views" in another main "View" and in those two "Views" I'm putting multiple images. And if not, what should I use?

Basically I wan't to make one image from multiple parts and I want to control all the parts at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer would be **Yes.**

It is a good practice to use Views for grouping(Creating a hierarchy). In addition to providing its own content, a view can act as a container for other views that creates a Parent-Child relationship.

The creation of this type of relationship has implications for both the visual appearance of your application and the application’s behavior. [See this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW24)

View Programming guide provides a section on [Creating and Managing a View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW47)